# Every ordered field has a countably infinite subset.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is the following argument correct?

**Theorem.** Every ordered field has countably infinite subset.

*Proof.* Let $F$ be an arbitrary ordered field. From definition $\textbf{1.1.5}$, we know that there exists a $1\in F$ such that $1\ne 0$, from the very same definition we also know that $x+y\in F$, whenever $x,y\in F$, implying 
$$A = \{1,1+1,1+1+1,\dots\}\subseteq F$$ 
To prove the claim in question then it is sufficient to demonstrate that $A$ consists of distinct elements. Proposition $\textbf{1.1.8}$ shows that $x^2>0$ whenever $x\neq 0$, thus in particular $1>0$, definition $\textbf{1.1.7}$ clause $(i)$ together with definition $\textbf{1.1.1}$ clause $\textit{(ii)}$ implies that 
$$\cdots>1+1+1+1>1+1+1>1+1>1$$
appealing then to definition $\textbf{1.1.1}$ clause $\textit{(i)}$ then implies that $\sum_{i=1}^{j}1\neq\sum_{i=1}^{k} 1$ whenever $j>k$ consequently all elements of the set $A$ are distinct as required.

$\blacksquare$

**Note:**

Definition $\textbf{1.1.5}$ is just the standard definition of a field.

Definition $\textbf{1.1.7}$: An field $F$ is said to be an ordered field if it is also an ordered set such that

- $(i)$  For any $x,y,z\in F$ $x<y$ implies $x+z<y+z$
- $(ii)$ For any $x,y\in F$, $x>0$ and $y>0$ implies $xy>0$

Definition $\textbf{1.1.1}$: An ordered set is a set $S$, together with a relation $<$ such that

- $(i)$ For any $x,y\in S$, exactly one of $x<y$,$x=y$ or $y<x$ holds.
- $(ii)$ If $x<y$ and $y<z$ then $x<z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is pretty solid, nice work!

The only thing I'd suggest to make the proof more complete would be to explicitly state your bijection between $A$ and the naturals. I know this is a simple one in this case, but there are many instances where the bijection may be harder to see, so it's good to get into a habit of writing it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reponse. I appreciate your comment concerning the explicit mention of the bijection aswell.